# string split and conditional paste

Tags: r, string, gsub, stringr, grepl

I am dealing with a dataframe which is as follows

```
        id            Comments
        1             The apple fell far from the mango tree
        2             I was born under a mango tree and a wandering star      
        3             Mules are made for packing and Mangoes for eating
```

I am interested in 4 words before the word mango and 4 words after, including the word mango.

The final dataset would appear like this.

```
        id            Comments
        1             far from the mango tree
        2             born under a mango tree and a      
        3             for packing and Mangoes for eating
```

Here's the test reproducible dataset

```
df <- read.table(text="Id,Comment
 1,The apple fell far from the mango tree
                 2,I was born under a mango tree and a wandering star      
                 3,Mules are made for packing and Mangoes for eating", header=T, sep=",")
```

Any insight on this much appriciated

Comment: what about cases that don't have 4 words before or after? Do you want to exclude those cases?

Comment: and can there be multiple mangoes

Comment: @bdeonovic That case seems to be covered in the example, e.g., id=1 has only one word after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a very good `stringi` package and regex technique:

```
library(stringi)
apply(df,1, function(myrow){
   stri_match_all_regex(myrow[2], "(\\p{L}+\\p{Z}){0,3}(mango\\p{L}*|Mango\\p{L}*)(\\p{Z}\\p{L}+){0,3}")[[1]][1,1]
   })
```

So I get from 0 to 3 words before `mango` (`(\\p{L}+\\p{Z}){0,3}`), after that mango or Mango with additional letters in the end (`(mango\\p{L}*|Mango\\p{L}*)`) and after that again from 0 to 3 words (`(\\p{Z}\\p{L}+){0,3}`)

Where `\p{Z}` is a whitespace and `\p{L}` is a letter.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
sapply(
  strsplit(as.character(df$Comment), " "),
  function(x){
    w = grep("[m|M]ango", x)[1]
    paste(x[ seq(max(1,w-3), min(length(x),w+3)) ], collapse=" ") 
  }
)
# [1] "far from the mango tree"           
# [2] "born under a mango tree and a"     
# [3] "for packing and Mangoes for eating"
```

The `grep(...)[1]` means that only the first mango match is used.

Comment: thanks bud, this work great if there was no N or missin data. If there was any then it crashed.

Comment: @KingFrazier Whoops, didn't expect it to crash anything. Glad you got something that works